# What's the story behind the Mitt Romney's tax return information blackmail

Tags: news-coverage, hacking

On the [6th of September, 2012 CNN reported](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/09/06/politics/romney-tax-threat/index.html) that a hacker group got a hold of Mitt Romney's tax return information and demanded a ransom of 1 million dollars equivalent in bitcoins to be paid for not revealing the information, or for revealing it instantly. What is the full story behind the hack and blackmail? Was the ransom paid, or was the data revealed?

Comment: IMHO this question is not a good fit for the site. It's not really about Bitcoin but about some blackmailing where they happened to use Bitcoin. I'll see what others have to say.

Comment: @D.H.: I think it fits. At this point in Bitcoin's life, this story is about as much about Bitcoin as it is about Romney. In 10 years time, hopefully this would not be the case for a similar story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 3 BTC paid on the "release" side, and 0.72 BTC paid on the "don't release" side.

So it brought in under $50 USD worth.

And the deadline passed with no tax returns.

- http://www.dailydot.com/news/blackmailers-50-dollars-bitcoin-romney-taxes/